# How do I get remote login IP to my machine from terminal on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, ip, remote-access

I want to be able to obtain the IP from a bash script. The same one I obtain going to System Preferences => Sharing => Remote Login.

Does anyone know how to do it? I am running Mac OS 10.9.4.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Again**

If you just want the IP addresses, you can do this:

```
ifconfig -a | awk '/inet /{print $2}'
```

**Updated**

You could try `scutil` like this:

```
scutil --get HostName
```

or maybe this:

```
scutil --get LocalHostName
```

or maybe this:

```
scutil --get ComputerName
```

**Original Answer**

Use `hostname`, like this:

```
hostname
```

Or, if you want it in a variable to use with `ssh`

```
address=$(hostname)
ssh $address
```

Comment: hostname command just returns:
local, and my remote login credentials look like that on the current network: my_user@192.68.100.29, so that is not going to work.

Comment: this does not get me there either. but I solved it like this:
`IPS=$(for x in $(netstat -i | grep en[0-9] | awk '{print $1}' | uniq); do ipconfig getifaddr $x; done)`. That gives the list of IP addresses at which the local machine is available at the current network. Thanks anyway Mark!

Comment: If you just want the IP addresses, you can do it more simply than that - see my updated answer. I understood from your question that you wanted the name though.

Comment: I ask for IP in the question. But thanks Mark again.